# How do you remove spaces between two strings in java hsa console?

Tags: java

```
public class TestParse
{
    static Console c;           // The output console

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        c = new Console ();
        String userNum = c.readString ();
        String userNum2 = userNum.replaceAll ("\\p{Z}","");
        c.println (userNum2);

   } // main method
} // TestParse class
```

The input is supposed to be one digit followed by a space and then another digit. Every time I try that, it only prints the first digit. How do I fix that? It should print the two digits without a space between them. I already tried using `st.replaceAll("\\s+","")` and `st.replaceAll("\\s","")`

Comment: Compile errors: `Console()` is a private constructor, and both `readString()` and `println(s)` are not functions in the `Console` class.

Comment: What you have should work. Are you sure `readString` is reading the full input correctly?

Comment: You're right, readString wasn't reading the full input. It worked after I changed that line to readLine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String userNum2 = unserNum.replaceAll("( )+", "");
```

Or

```
String userNum2 = unserNum.replaceAll(" ", "");
```